# C: Function parameter input changes seemingly randomly

Tags: c, arrays, function, memory-management, double

I wasn't able to find a question like this already, but please feel free to redirect me to an answer should it exist.

Below I have done my best to replicate a bug I have encountered, with as little code as possible. **I have removed as many variables as possible while keeping the bug, and have hardcoded the values that seem necessary to replicate it; I have only left variables that must be variables for this bug to occur according to my tests**. First, I pass a value `epsilon`, a `double` with value `1.0/3.0`. Then, I pass this to `a_function` which takes both `epsilon` and some arrays. I perform some basic copying on parts of the input arrays, after which `epsilon` changes value very slightly. Below is a code excerpt, where I have removed declarations and `include` statements.

```
int main(int argc, int argv[])
{
  /* It doesn't matter what these arrays are filled with, 
     but they must be of length 13 */
  int array1[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int array2[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int array3[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int array4[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int a_value = 2;
  double a_double= 1.0/3.0;

  printf("a_double: %.10lf\n", a_double);
  a_function(array1, array2, array3, array4, a_value, a_double);
  return 0;
}

void a_function(int *array1, int *array2, int *array3, int *array4,  
                int a_value, double a_double)
{
  int m = 1;
  /* This occurs regardless of value assigned to m (provided the 
     for loop is appropriately changed to not go out of bounds) */
  int temp_array1[m];  
  int temp_array2[m];
  for(int i = 12; i < 13; i++)
  {
    temp_array1[i] = array1[i];
    temp_array2[i] = array2[i];
  }

  printf("a_double: %.10lf\n", a_double);
}
```

Running this code gives the output

```
$ ./a.out
a_double: 0.3333333333
a_double: 0.3333332539
```

It seems that the bug doesn't occur when:

- The length of the arrays change.
- The termination condition of the `for` loop changes to something other than the last element (for example, `i < 12` does not result in the bug).
- Any of the included parameters are removed.
- When the value of `m` is hardcoded: it doesn't matter what the value of `m` is, but if the arrays are defined in terms of it, the bug occurs.
- When I run this code directly in `main` (i.e. without a function).
- When I have my first `printf` of `a_double` on function entry (i.e. directly before `int m = 1`).

What could be the cause of this bug? My guess is it is something very semantic to do with function calling and temporary variables in C, but I don't know. Please let me know if I can give any clarifications.

Comment: thought the formal answer is UB, what is probably happening is that you override the stack which holds the input parameter/s when you perform out of bounds assignments of `temp_array2` and `temp_array1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has undefined behavior:

```
  int m = 1;
  int temp_array1[m];  
  for(int i = 12; i < 13; i++)
  {
    temp_array1[i] = array1[i];
  }
```

The loop executes once, with `i` being 12.  But the length of the array is 1, so the write is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks! That is a highly embarrassing error. Do you have any clue why if I have a `printf` in the first line of the function the value does not occur? Or is that just the way of undefined behaviour?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.